# Creating a confirmation box jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a website where i have comments . now people can delete comments using `.del` button

```
$('.del').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('cmnt-id');
    $.post(url,{
       //data sent
    },function(data){
         //remove the comment div
    })
});
```

Now what i want is a confirmation box to be appear on screen which has simply 2 options `delete` and `cancel`. When someone presses `delete` it deletes but when pressed `cancel` it `returns false`.
But i dont know how do i do it.

***UPDATE***
I have my own confirmation box and dont wanna use any ***PLUGINS***

But how do i take em into action ?? 
 **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/3/)**

Comment: How could your fiddle works if you haven't selected the jQuery lib on fiddle options?

Comment: see update @DontVoteMeDown a

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
   //delete code, OK was pressed (confirmed), execute delete code
} else {
   //cancel was pressed return false
   return false;
}
```

No jquery needed nor fancy box.

If you need something fancy I would suggest using **JQuery UI** where you can use Dialog widget to have a confirm box.

**UPDATE**

```
var confirmed = false;
$('.del').click(function(){
   //show your confirm dialog
});

$('.confirm .yes').on('click', function() {
   //execute delete code
});

$('.confirm .no').on('click', function() {
   //code to close your confirm dialog
});
```

Comment: Now you go. But there's no need for the `confirmed` var anymore and your `return false` on *no* button callback is useless. You have to close the window in that callback.